# If we Shift a bit to left and left most becomes 1 then how to calculate?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I came to a strange problem. Here is the code:

```
public class ShiftLeft {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

      int c = 22;
      int d = c << 3;
      System.out.println("c << 3 = "+d);
 }

}
```

Answer is : 176 but let's do the calculation by hand.

```
+22 = 0001 0110
      1011 0000 <<3
```

As the left most bit is 1 so it has to be negative number.

```
Sign + magnitude = 1011 0000
       magnitude =  011 0000
                    100 1111 ---1s compliment


101 0000 ---2s compliment
adding left bit    1101 0000 =-80
```

Answer comes 176 only if we don't count left most bit as sign. Why is that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking about an `int` (`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0110`) as about a `byte` (`0001 0110`). But the `int` primitive type has `32` bits (double word), not just `8` bits.

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0110 (2)
<<
3
=
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1011 0000 (2)
=
176 (10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Because an int has more than 8 bits.

Comment: what will be the answer if it is calculated on 8 bits?

Comment: @mlhazan: Why don't you try it? Java's 8-bit integral type is `byte`. There's also [a full explanation of how `<<` works in the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).

Answer (score 2):

A 32-bit integer
`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1011 0000` is not negative.